# JQuery library extraction

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need to extract jquery library. jquery library contain many functions. But only few functions are using from this library. So I need to remove all the unnecessary functions from this library. Is there a easy way to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? If not, I doubt anyone will be able to help you. Are you trying to remove parts of jQuery?

Comment: I guess the _only_ way to do this is to open an unobfuscated jQuery source to your text editor, and then select the functions you don't need and press `Delete` ; ).

Comment: What functions exactly do you want to keep?

Comment: jQuery internally "eats its own dogfood" a lot, which means the library is not too modular; Removing one function means other functions in the library that use it will break.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Just open up the file and copy&paste out the functions you need. You don't specify which ones these are, so you will have to do the job yourself.

Long answer: Why do you want to do this? jQuery is just a library that makes writing js easier. That means that anything written in jQuery can be done with pure js. It would be much easier just to write the functions straight out. Also, many jQuery-methods depend on each other, which means that you can't just take one out of the core and expect it to work. It is much more difficult that that.

And like Done pointed out, there's no really good reason for doing this. You may reduce the filesize a bit, but with today's speed downloading a minimized library like js does not take long. If you use google's cdn most people already has it cached already.

To sum it up: Copy&paste if you really, really have to, but I strongly suggest not doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to remove these functions ?
If it's for the file size you can look at lighter framework such as MooTools, or you have jquery-min.
You can also edit the jquery file with a good editor.

Comment: can you please tell me what are those editors? Actually one thing is file size. And it is the one of a requirement of our cient

Comment: The editor that you wanted, you will need refactoring a lot.

As OptimusCrime said : "many jQuery-methods depend on each other, which means that you can't just take one out of the core and expect it to work. It is much more difficult that that."